# Undefined array key "year"

Tags: php, laravel

I installed https://github.com/morilog/jalali package in my project.

I want to convert the Jalali date to Gregorian and then store it in the database.

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Competition::query()->create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'team_a_id' => $request->team_a_id,
        'team_b_id' => $request->team_b_id,
        'date' => jalalitomiladi($request->date),
        'time' => $request->time,
        'league' => $request->league,
        'live' => $request->live,
        'end_at' => jalalitomiladi($request->end_at),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('admin.competitions.index');
}
```

helpers.php

```
<?php

use Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils;

if (! function_exists('jalalitomiladi')) {
    function jalalitomiladi($date)
    {
        $year = intval(substr($date, 0,4));
        $month = intval(substr($date, 5,2));
        $day = intval(substr($date, 8,2));
        return CalendarUtils::createDatetimeFromFormat("$year-$month-$day", $date);
    }
}
```

I see this error

[image: error]

Comment: FYI: you don't need to do `Competition::query()->create([...])`, you can simply do `Competition::create([...])`. Also, does this issue still happen if you set the `date` to `now()`? So,`[..., 'date' => now(), ...]`

Comment: My form is like this a user should select a calendar. https://frontbackend.com/storage/resources/Perfect-DateTimePicker/perfect-date-time-picker-jquery.gif

Comment: How to convert the Jalali date to Gregorian and then store it in the database.

Answer (score 2):

In the [github page](https://github.com/morilog/jalali), there is examples of how to convert dates into this package you are using.

```
return CalendarUtils::createDatetimeFromFormat("$year-$month-$day", $date);
```

You are injecting the date parameters into the format parameter, i would assume it should be like this instead.

```
return CalendarUtils::createDatetimeFromFormat('y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: @mrhm My problem did not solve yet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQE9.png

Comment: what is dd($date);

Answer (score 0):

In the package's readme, you can use [toGregorian](https://github.com/morilog/jalali#togregorianjyear-jmonth-jday) method. But i hope [this gist](https://gist.github.com/faridfr/da19aed52452ec8e0c01ccc030d5fe85) can help you so.

Comment: My problem did not solve yet, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHN4.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi , notice that the result of (toGregorian) method is an array. if you want to store it in the DB string column, you can use implode("-",$arr) before saving in DB.